# How does recursion work in this small problem in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

So iam looking at this short piece of code using recursion to computer powers and if i give it a value of Riase_2(2,4) it returns 16 which is correct.However iam confused on how whe we reach exp==0 it returns 16 and not just 1? also how does the abase * Raise_2(abase, exp-1) work what is the abase ebing times by?
Hope someone can clear this up for me thanks.

```
static int Raise_2(int abase, int exp)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Loops 2 : {abase} {exp}");
    int outerLoop = 0;
    if (exp == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        outerLoop++;
        return abase * Raise_2(abase, exp - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The magic is in the other return statement, `return abase * Raise_2(abase, exp - 1);`. For R(2, 4) it will eventually do all this: `R(2, 4) = 2 * R(2, 3)` --> `2 * 2 * R(2, 2)` --> `2 * 2 * 2 * R(2, 1)` --> `2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * R(2, 0)` --> `2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1` --> `16`.

Comment: The variable `outerLoop` is completely useless.

Comment: "the abase ebing times by": what language is that ?

Answer (score 2):

If you run with `Raise(2,4)`, the computation works as followed:

```
2 * Raise(2,3)
==
2 * 2 * Raise(2,2)
==
2 * 2 * 2 * Raise(2,1)
==
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * Raise(2,0)
==
2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 1 = 16
```

Maybe you can understand that better with a debugger.

Comment: You're missing a `* 2` in the 3rd iteration

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

We want to check that `Raise` does return the value of `abase^exp` where both `abase` and `exp` are integers.

First notice that if `exp` is `0`, the function returns `1`, which is indeed `abase^0`.

Then assume that the function works correctly for `exp-1` (i.e. it does return `abase^(exp-1)`). If you call the function `Raise(abase, exp)`, it computes `abase.abase^(exp-1)`, which is equal to `abase^exp`. Hence by induction, the function works for all integers (unless overflow occurs).

For integers, overflow can soon arise: `Raise(2, 32)` will, as well as `Raise(3,20)`, `Raise(4, 16)`, `Raise(5, 14)`...